# Импорт геометок из Google maps

Tags: java, android, android-studio, api, google-maps-api

В приложении есть Google карта, каким образом сделать так, чтобы она отображала только геометки достопримечательностей?

Comment: думаю, вам лучше штудировать api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я применил следующий скрипт:

```js
function initialize() {
               var mapOptions = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.4809681,15.5604045),
               zoom: 7,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
            }; 
    
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
               mapOptions);
            
            
            var ob2 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.658096,16.355235),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/castle.svg'
            });

            var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Kalmar Castle</h3><img src="../../../sights/images/kalmar-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../sights/en/kalmar-en.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob2, 'click', function() {
               infowindow2.open(map, ob2);
            }); 
            
            
            var ob3 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.6645407,16.3653616),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/church.svg'
            });

            var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Kalmar Cathedral</h3><img src="../../../church/images/kalmar-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../church/en/kalmar.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob3, 'click', function() {
               infowindow3.open(map, ob3);
            });
            
            
            var ob4 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.4098582,15.5230975),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/museum.svg'
            });

            var infowindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Swedish Air Force Museum</h3><img class=img-l src="../../../museums-r/images/air-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../museums-r/en/air.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob4, 'click', function() {
               infowindow4.open(map, ob4);
            });
            
            
            var ob5 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.410553,15.616078),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/castle.svg'
            });

            var infowindow5 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Linköping Castle</h3><img src="../../../sights/images/linkoping-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../sights/en/linkoping-en.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob5, 'click', function() {
               infowindow5.open(map, ob5);
            });
            
            
            var ob6 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.411052,15.616588),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/church.svg'
            });

            var infowindow6 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Linköping Cathedral</h3><img src="../../../church/images/linkoping-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../church/en/linkoping.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob6, 'click', function() {
               infowindow6.open(map, ob6);
            });
            
            
            var ob7 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.5504141,16.0400284),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/castle.svg'
            });

            var infowindow7 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Löfstad Castle</h3><img src="../../../sights/images/lofstad-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../sights/en/lofstad-en.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob7, 'click', function() {
               infowindow7.open(map, ob7);
            });   
            
            
            var ob8 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.445997,14.883563),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/castle.svg'
            });

            var infowindow8 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Vadstena Castle</h3><img src="../../../sights/images/vadstena-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../sights/en/vadstena-en.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob8, 'click', function() {
               infowindow8.open(map, ob8);
            });
            
            
            var ob9 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.4508051,14.8913536),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/church.svg'
            });

            var infowindow9 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Vadstena Abbey</h3><img src="../../../church/images/vadstena-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../church/en/vadstena.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob9, 'click', function() {
               infowindow9.open(map, ob9);
            });
            
           var ob10 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.4810449,15.5147372),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/church.svg'
            });

            var infowindow10 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Vreta Abbey</h3><img src="../../../church/images/vreta-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../church/en/vreta.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob10, 'click', function() {
               infowindow10.open(map, ob10);
            });
            
           var ob11 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.87739,14.8120138),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/church.svg'
            });

            var infowindow11 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Växjö Cathedral</h3><img src="../../../church/images/vaxjo-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../church/en/vaxjo.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob11, 'click', function() {
               infowindow11.open(map, ob11);
            });
            
            
            var ob12 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.1614029,15.5995131),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/museum.svg'
            });

            var infowindow12 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Naval Museum</h3><img src="../../../museums-r/images/marinmuseum-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../museums-r/en/marinmuseum.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob12, 'click', function() {
               infowindow12.open(map, ob12);
            });
            
            
            var ob13 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.87054,16.64346),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/castle.svg'
            });

            var infowindow13 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Borgholm Castle</h3><img src="../../../sights/images/borgholm-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../sights/en/borgholm-en.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob13, 'click', function() {
               infowindow13.open(map, ob13);
            }); 
            
            
            var ob14 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.292902,16.484052),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/fortress.svg'
            });

            var infowindow14 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Eketorp fort</h3><img src="../../../sights/images/eketorp-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../sights/en/eketorp-en.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob14, 'click', function() {
               infowindow14.open(map, ob14);
            });
            
            
            
            var ob15 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.1104337,15.5646414),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/fortress.svg'
            });
            
            var infowindow15 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Drottningskär Citadel</h3><img src="../../../sights/images/drottningskar-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../sights/en/drottningskar-en.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob15, 'click', function() {
               infowindow15.open(map, ob15);
            });
            
          }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Здесь вы объявляете карту и даете зоом и центр:

```js
function initialize() {
               var mapOptions = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.4809681,15.5604045),
               zoom: 7,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
            };
```

Здесь создаете объект, инфо-окно с информацией и фотографией объекта и возвращаете событие щелчка:

```js
var ob2 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.658096,16.355235),
               map: map,
               icon: '../../../maps_icons/castle.svg'
            });

            var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: '<div class="info"><h3>Kalmar Castle</h3><img src="../../../sights/images/kalmar-min.jpg" /><div style="clear:both"></div><a href="../../../sights/en/kalmar-en.html" target="_blank"><button>Read more</button></a></div>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(ob2, 'click', function() {
               infowindow2.open(map, ob2);
            });
```

Разумеется нужно создавать стили для содержания инфо-окон.